# Remove ":" from field two of CSV only and ignore other fields

Tags: regex, linux, bash, csv, sed

I've been trying to clean up the data in a csv file which contain data similar to this:

```
8979880, Number One : Exclusive Mix, 387387, http://www.smashhits.com
4844404, Top 40 : 1988, 3893938, http://www.best80s.com
48094940, Highlander:The Return, 489494, http://www.instantaccess.com
```

My goal is to replace the colon in field 2 with a space. Initially I used sed to replace the : with a spacelike so:

```sh
sed i "s/:/ /g" file.csv
```

This works in removing the colon but unfortunately this also removes the colon in the url which is not what I want. How can I specify that I only want the command to affect the data in field 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gnu sed like this:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*,[^,]*):/\1 /g' file.csv
```

**Explanation**

- `^` anchors the expression at the start of each line
- now `[^,]*,` matches the first field including the separator
- and then `[^,]*:` matches from the second field to the `:`
- the parenthises `^(...):` take care that everything up to but not including the `:` in the second field is captured into `\1`
- finally the replacement with `\1` (there is a space after the `\1` does the replacement of the `:` with space on line where the regex matched

Comment: This is perfect actually, it grabs exactly the second field as the OP wants.

Comment: by adding branch and label like this : `sed -r ':b s/^([^,]*,[^,]*):/\1 /g; t b'`, we can also deal with multiple `:` in the second field.

Comment: Spot on, thanks Lars, that's perfect and thanks for extra info in explaining what each piece of the code does

Comment: I just also tried applying this to full stops in the second field, replacing the ":" in the same code with a "."   but this doesn't seem to work as expected

Comment: Careful with simple solutions; CSV allows commas in (quoted) fields. May or may not apply to the original example data.

Comment: @abbie The dot itself is a metacharacter in regular expressions. You need to escape it. i.e. use `\.` instead of a simple dot.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do

```
awk '/:/{sub(/:/, " ")} 1' file.csv
```

With `/:/` you match the first occurrence of :

With `{sub(/:/, " ")}` you replace : with a space

`1` simply prints the line.

Comment: Very elegant! I always forget to use awk when asked for "simple" substitutions.

Comment: The only issue with this is that if there is a title without a : then the first occurrence becomes the : in the url

Comment: @abbie The issue of `:` not in $2 can be fixed by *beeing more specific* like this: `awk -F, -v 'OFS=","' '$2 ~/:/ {gsub(/:/, " ", $2)} 1' file.csv` . Where we tell awk to use `:` as field separator  and limit the condition and substitution to `$2`. Alas then we have to tell awk to use `,` as output field separator (`OFS`),  too.

Comment: Yes, this solution admits that the number and the pattern of parameters are always the same.